# Is there a way to check or create a retention line in sabre api?

Tags: php, sabre, sabredav

All payloads are valid and sabre's API return no error and the booking was made successfully. But there is no retention line when checking it on Sabre workspace. How can I check if there's a retention line created and what can I do to manually create it?

Answer (score 0):

we can create manually using the sabre API and in GDS as well

Sabre API:

SabreCommandLLSRQ

### Below are the Four  comments should be entered in SabreCommandLLSRQ and save it using EndTrandsaction- Then do retrieve the PNR

1. *PNR
2. 0OTHAAGK1BOS24AUG-KEEP PNR ACTIVE
3. 6RD
4. ER

---

Explanation

1. *PNR-- To retrieve the PNR

0OTHAAGK1BOS24AUG-KEEP PNR ACTIVE---

1. 0-Format to add OTH
2. OTH- retention
3. AAGK-You can give anything here according to your requirement
4. 1BOS24AUG--Date and route

If its GDS enter these four comments.